# PHP IF / OR Not Working

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm setting up a small magazine with several sections that all work from the same PHP page.

I'd like it to redirect people back to the home page if they are not on an official section. So for this my code is:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_GET["section"])) {
      $section = $_GET["section"];
  } else {
      header("Location: $site_url");
      exit();
  }

  if ($section !== 'gallery' || $section !== 'magazine' || $section !== 'picks' || $section !== 'customs' || $section !== 'editor') {
      header("Location: $site_url");
      exit();
  }
?>
```

The problem is, when I visit `localhost/results.php?section=gallery`, I'm redirected back to the home page, even though it is in the If statement. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Try ANDing your possible sections, not ORing them.... PHP is doing exactly what you tell it to do

Comment: If *any one* of those tests is true, you go back to the home page. Several of them will always be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will *always* be true:

```
$section !== 'gallery' || $section !== 'magazine' || ...
```

Because the same variable can never simultaneously be more than one value.  I suspect you meant to use `&&`:

```
$section !== 'gallery' && $section !== 'magazine' && ...
```